# Entity Framework Core 2.0.2 FromSql has a bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created the following function

```
public IDictionary<string, object> RunSql<T>(string spName, IList<SqlParameter> spParamList) where T : class
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    try
    {
            string sqlCommand = $"{spName} " +
                                string.Join(", ", spParamList.Select(p => p.ParameterName + (p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output ? " OUTPUT" : "")));
            var data = _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FromSql(sqlCommand, spParamList.ToArray()).ToList();

            var spOutputList = spParamList.Where(p => p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output).Select(p => new { Name = p.ParameterName, p.Value });

            foreach (var outParam in spOutputList)
                result.Add(outParam.Name, outParam.Value);

            result.Add("data", data);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

which I call like this:

```
var result = _bingoRepository.RunSql<ProductInventory>("scn.usp_receiveProductInventory", sqlParamList);
```

The stored procedure `scn.usp_receiveProductInventory` sometimes returns nothing (except output parameters) sometimes a record set of type `ProductInventory`.

When I call it first time as soon as I start my web API I get error

> The required column 'Bin' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

Where `Bin` is a key property of `ProductInventory`.

It happens when `scn.usp_receiveProductInventory` returns nothing. Then I call it again when `scn.usp_receiveProductInventory` returns a record set and that is successful. Then I go back and make the call exactly the same as the first time and everything is fine - no errors, output parameters returned properly.

It appears to me that there is something wrong with Entity Framework Core. Is there a away to make this code run reliably?

Comment: Had a similar problem this helped me: https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/07/entity-framework-core-and-calling-a-stored-proceduce/#comment-60582
For me it wasn't relevant what stored proc will return I only wanted to execute and make sure it's successfully done.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I resolved this problem the old fashion way calling  ExecuteReaderAsync from SqlCommand but that was not the point of this question. Is it possible to make it work reliably still using FromSql?